# How to make regular expressoin to match similar letters with python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a python code to detect specific algebraic laws in a regular expression and come up with an equivalent to these expressions. For example, "a+a=a". So, if "a+a" was entered as input, then it will be shortened to only "a". But this could really be any sequence such as "b+b" or "xyz+xyz" etc...

The question is, How to make a regular expression in python "using re module or any other module" to detect if the letters before the "+" sign are similar to the ones after the "+" sign, and replace the whole expression e.g. "a+a" with only "a"?

I know that this can be done in a brute force way as I did in the code, but there are uncountable regular expressions that could come in the same form and it is almost impossible to do it my way.

My idea:

```
import re
x = input("Enter regex: ")
expressions = {"a+a":"a", "b+b":"b", "c+c":"c", "ab+ab":"ab"}

def rep(regex, newregex):
    pattern = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape,newregex)))
    def matcher(match):
        return newregex[match.group(0)]
    return pattern.sub(matcher, regex)
rep(x, expressions )
```

Comment: you can use a `capturing group` to do this easily in this case `(\w)\+\1` or `([a-zA-Z])\+\1` would work `()` is used to create the group and `\1` just refers to the first group

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple,

```py
eq = "abcdef+abcdef" # example string

eq = eq.split("+")
if eq[0] == eq[1]: eq = eq[0]
else: eq = "+".join(eq)

print(eq)
>>> abcdef
```